# Are auto placeholder types and explicit template types equivalent in C++20?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Are auto placeholder types and explicitly defined template type parameters completely equivalent?

I've read that the spec states that "A placeholder-type-specifier designates a placeholder type that will be replaced later by deduction from an initializer."

(9.2.8.5 Placeholder type specifiers
http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#:auto
)

So are the following equivalent as far as instantiation, const types, reference types, etc?

```
void f1(auto param) {
     using T = decltype(param);
     T t1;
}

template <class T> void f2(T param ) {
     T t1;
}
```

Comment: Have a read of [Abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template) eg (from the link) `void f1(auto); // same as template<class T> void f(T)`

Answer (score 7):

They are functionally equivalent, but it's important to note that the standard does not declare them to be *actually* equivalent. That is, `f1` and `f2` work in virtually every way the same. But you could never do this:

```
void f1(auto); //declaration of a template.

template<typename T>
void f1(T t) //definition of a template.
{...}
```

The declaration of `f1` does not match the *definition* of `f1`.

Comment: That would probably be ill-formed, no diagnostic required?

Comment: @user17732522: Probably, but I don't recall the details.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes (this is called being functionally equivalent but not equivalent)